# Complex Forms in rails (has_and_belongs_to_many)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, controller

Right now, I'm in the middle of actually building a Project Management application, and I'm kind-of stuck on the way i should build this form. At the moment of adding a project I would like to select the clients that would be included in the project. Here's the code to a few things of interest:

Project Model
Project Migration
Clients Model
Clients Migration
Clients_Projects Migration table

http://pastebin.com/280MjR8i

What would be the best approach on building the Controller/View so far, i have this for the view, but i have no idea, what should be the take on the controller ->

http://pastebin.com/dHa8nAQZ

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use nested attributes for this. Check out Ryan Bates' railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1 and http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2.

You can add and remove clients for a project using this method. Using a list of checkboxes to select clients could be problematic for a large number of clients.

Comment: Thanks a lot, those screencasts saved my life :)

Answer (score 2):

In your controller, you must indicate to `.permit` that the list of ids is an array:

```
def client_params
  params[:client].permit(
    :name,
    :address,
    :phone,
    {:project_ids => []}
  ),
end
```

Then the *Rails magic* will work.

> source: https://coderwall.com/p/_1oejq

Comment: Brilliant! Simple and easy!

Comment: the `{}` are not required, at least in rails 4 just :project_ids => [] works